# Remove words before and after 4th occurrence of a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which has filename and I need to extract a part of the filename

Example:

```
filename

abc_sfrs1_sdfre_fdsj_2015419_154825.jpeg
asdac_cfwes_ssaare_fdsj_2015418_52584.jpeg
ezxc_afrs_hdeas_fdsj_2015416_15484.jpeg
rer_bfee_rre_fdsj_2015415_25485.jpeg
```

So the result set should be

```
2015419
2015418
2015416
2015415
```

the date occurrence will always happen after 4 the `_`.
Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is for `Sql Server` or `Mysql`

Comment: I need for `SQL Server` but so as to increase the scope I included both sql and Mysql

Comment: @Zack you shouldn't use tags not relevant to your question. Yes you will get a broader audience but the way to retrieve these results will not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `Cross Apply` and `Charindex` string function

**Demo**

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES ('abc_sfrs1_sdfre_fdsj_2015419_154825.jpeg'),
                        ('asdac_cfwes_ssaare_fdsj_2015418_52584.jpeg'),
                        ('ezxc_afrs_hdeas_fdsj_2015416_15484.jpeg'),
                        ('rer_bfee_rre_fdsj_2015415_25485.jpeg')) tc (string))
SELECT EXTRACTED_DATA = Substring(string, fur + 1, fiv - fur - 1)
FROM   cte
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', string))) cs (fst)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', string, fst + 1))) cs1 (scd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', string, scd + 1))) cs2 (thd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', string, thd + 1))) cs4 (fur)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', string, fur + 1))) cs5 (fiv)
```

**Result**

```
EXTRACTED_DATA
--------------
2015419
2015418
2015416
2015415
```

**Update**

For your table it should be something like this

```
SELECT Substring(filename, fur + 1, fiv - fur - 1) AS EXTRACTED_DATA
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', filename))) cs (fst)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', filename, fst + 1))) cs1 (scd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', filename, scd + 1))) cs2 (thd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', filename, thd + 1))) cs4 (fur)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('_', filename, fur + 1))) cs5 (fiv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much MotoGP, can you let me know a process of fetching using direct column name ? i.e. filename Column name and also save as a new column i.e. the date should be a new column.